# Send Image with SOAP Message

Tags: java, xml, soap, encoding

I want to add my JPG to my SOAP Request and I need to convert it i guess.

When I send the same soapMessage with SoapUI(it works) I can see that the encoding of my image is like this:

[0xff][0xd8][0xff][0xe0][0x0][0x10]JFIF[0x0][0x1][0x1][0x1][0x0]H[0x0]H[0x0][0x0][0xff][0xe1][0x19]tExif[0x0][0x0]MM[0x0]*[0x0][0x0][0x0][0x8][0x0][0xc][0x1][0x0][0x0][0x4][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x1][0x0][0x0][0xc][0xc0][0x1][0x1][0x0][0x4][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x1][0x0][0x0][0x7],[0x1][0xf][0x0][0x2][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x8][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x9e][0x1][0x10][0x0][0x2][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x8][0x0][0x0][0x0][0xa6][0x1][0x12][0x0][0x3][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x1][0x0][0x1][0x0][0x0][0x1][0x1a][0x0][0x5][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x1][0x0][0x0][0x0][0xae][0x1][0x1b][0x0][0x5][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x1][0x0][0x0][0x0][0xb6][0x1]([0x0][0x3][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x1][0x0][0x2][0x0][0x0][0x1]1[0x0][0x2][0x0][0x0][0x0][0xc][0x0][0x0][0x0][0xbe][0x1]2[0x0][0x2][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x14][0x0][0x0][0x0][0xca][0x2][0x13][0x0][0x3][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x1][0x0][0x1][0x0][0x0][0x87]i[0x0][0x4][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x1][0x0][0x0][0x0][0xde][0x0][0x0][0x3]Bsamsung[0x0]SM-P600[0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0]H[0x0][0x0][0x0][0x1][0x0][0x0][0x0]H[0x0][0x0][0x0][0x1]P600XXUDOJ3[0x0]2016:04:08 14:32:04[0x0][0x0][0x1c][0x82][0x9a][0x0][0x5][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x1][0x0][0x0][0x2]4[0x82][0x9d][0x0][0x5][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x1][0x0][0x0][0x2]<[0x88]"[0x0][0x3][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x1][0x0][0x2][0x0][0x0][0x88]'[0x0][0x3][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x1][0x0]P[0x0][0x0][0x90][0x0][0x0][0x7][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x4]0220[0x90][0x3][0x0][0x2][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x14][0x0][0x0][0x2]D[0x90][0x4][0x0][0x2][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x14][0x0][0x0][0x2]X[0x92][0x1][0x0][\n]"

So I think I should encode my image exactly like that before adding my image (JPG) to my message.

How can i encode my image like this please?

Comment: Show us what you tried so far. Nobody here will do all your work for you. Even a little more information regarding the used stack, etc. would help. Have a look here [http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I tried during 1 week and I dont put any line of my code because I wanted to see others ideas. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send an image using SOAP you have to encode it in one of these formats :

- base64Binary
- SwA - SOAP with Attachments
- MTOM

Then in your SOAP request you can use the xsi:type to declare your encoding type :

```
 <submitClaim>
  <accountNumber>5XJ45-3B2</accountNumber>
  <eventType>accident</eventType>
  <image imageType="jpg" xsi:type="base64binary">
   4f3e9b0...(rest of encoded image)
  </image>
 </submitClaim>
```

In your java code you have to read the BufferedImage and convert it to a string and then add it to your SOAP request:

```
public static String encodeToString(BufferedImage image, String type) {  
        String imageString = null;  
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  

        try {  
            ImageIO.write(image, type, bos);  
            byte[] imageBytes = bos.toByteArray();  

            BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();  
            imageString = encoder.encode(imageBytes);  

            bos.close();  
        } catch (IOException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }  
        return imageString;  
    }
```

Comment: Thanks it works when i encode my image in Base64 and i put this encoding between <image></image>